# How to store a large folder in a single file without compression

Tags: shell, files, compression

I want to take a 78gb folder and store it in a single file (for upload into a cloud service), as if I am compressing it in an archive, but I don't want any compression (I don't have that much CPU time available). Is there anyway that I can accomplish this, perhaps a terminal command I don't know about?

Comment: there is `tar` command in linux. `tar -cf long.file.tar folder`

Comment: FYI: There are fast compression programs, some which will be faster than your disk write speed, and many that will be faster than your network. Using one of those will actually speed things up, if the data is at all compressible. E.g., `lzop` is designed for speed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `tar`:
`tar -cf my_big_folder.tar /my/big/folder`

Restore the archive with `tar -xf my_big_folder.tar -C /`

**-C** will change to the root directory to restore your archive since the archive created above contains absolute paths.

**EDIT**: Due to the relatively big size of the archive, it'd be best to send it [directly] to its final location, using SSH or a mount point of the cloud resource/folder. For example, as [Cole Johnson suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197134/#comment-330672) :

```
tar -cf /network/mount/point/my_big_folder.tar /my/big/folder
```

or

```
tar -c /my/big/folder | ssh example.com "cat > my_big_folder.tar"
```

**EDIT**: As [Blacklight Shining also suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197134/how-to-store-a-large-folder-in-a-single-file-without-compression#comment330936_197137), If you want to avoid absolute paths, you can change to the big folder's parent and `tar` from there:

```
tar -cf /network/mount/point/my_big_folder.tar \
    -C /my/big/folder/location the_big_folder
```

or

```
tar -cC /my/big/folder/location the_big_folder | \
ssh example.com "cat > my_big_folder.tar"
```

---

## Personal reflexions

Whether to include relative or absolute paths is a matter of personal preference.

There are cases absolute paths are obvious, e.g. for a restore in a disaster recovery situation. For local projects or collections it's common to archive a directory tree from the desired folder's parent so as to avoid cluttering the current directory, in case the archive is accidentally unpacked in-place. If *big_folder* lies somewhere deep in a [standard *NIX hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), it may make some sense to start archiving the first non-standard folder where *big_folder* deviates from and its directory tree from there.

Finally — going pedantic here — `tar` archive members are *always* relative since **a)** they may be restored in any directory and **b)** `tar` removes the leading `/` when creating an archive. I personally tend to always use **-C** when unpacking an archive.

Comment: To clarify the edit: do `tar -cf /network/mount/point/folder.tar /folder` instead of tarring to the local computer and then uploading if you can

Comment: Exact. The more I read my edit, the more I think it looks confused. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: It's worth noting the way to _avoid_ making the archive with absolute paths: `tar -cf $archive.tar -C $source_dir .`. If the destination machine doesn't have directory with the same path as the source directory, you'll _need_ to do that. Just make sure to `-C` into a new directory when you extract (`mkdir $destination_dir && tar -xf $archive.tar -C $destination_dir`); else the archive contents will get dumped into whatever directory you happen to be in.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative: cpio

```
(cd /my/big/folder && find . -depth -print0 | cpio -0o > myfolder.cpio)
```

Unpacking to current directory:

```
cpio -id < myfolder.cpio
```

Caveats:

- If use `find /my/big/folder` instead of `cd`, the archive will contain full paths and extraction will try to follow them;
- Big files (> 2GB) may be a problem;

Comment: Cpio tends to be much slower than tar, though, if used with the default blocksize of 512. (http://fixunix.com/sco/89900-cpio-performance-vs-tar-bit-mystery.html)

Answer (score 0):

To store a large folder into a single file without compression and with a progress bar, one can use the following one-line command:

```
tar -cf - ./Downloads/ | (pv -p --timer --rate --bytes > backup.tar)
```

The command will keep the original folder intact.

Requirements:

```
sudo apt-get install -y pv
```

Demo (in my case, my folder is `./Downloads/` and my output file is `adb_int.tar`):

[image]

Credits: the command combines user86969's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197137/16704) with [Jakuje](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/121504/jakuje)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251696/16704).