# pv (progress bar) and gzip

Tags: command-line, gzip

Why is this not possible?

```
pv ${dest_file} | gzip -1
```

`pv` is a progress bar

## error

```
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
   0 B 0:00:00 [   0 B/s] [>                                   ]  0%
```

This works

```
pv ${file_in} | tar -Jxf - -C /outdir
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Did you read do docs of `pv` and `gzip` command?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve is to see the progress bar of the compression process. But it is not possible using `pv`. It shows only transfer progress, which you can achieve by something like this (anyway, it is the [first link](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/9559/gzip-compression-with-progress-bar-and-remaining-time-displayed) in the google):

```
pv input_file | gzip > compressed_file
```

The progress bar will run fast, and then it will wait for compression, which is not observable anymore using `pv`.

But you can do that other way round and watch the output stream, bot here you will not be able to see the actual progress, because `pv` does not know the actual size of the compressed file:

```
gzip <input_file | pv > compressed_file
```

The best I found so far is the one from [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5247/tar-directory-and-compress-it-with-showing-progress-and-disk-io-limits) even with rate limiting and compression of directories:

```
$D=directory
tar pcf - $D | pv -s $(du -sb $D | awk '{print $1}') --rate-limit 500k | gzip > target.tar.gz
```

Comment: the progress bar is not working with `gzip input_file | pv > compressed_file`

Comment: it is, but it does not know the whole size of the compressed file so it just scans from the side to the side. The first one is probably better.

Comment: The progress bar doesn't run fast for me.

Comment: `gzip -c` is required to send output to stdout to allow it to be passed to `pv`, otherwise the progress bar won't work as there's no data going to `pv`  :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! You can also achieve this with something like `mysqldump ... | gzip | pv > output.sql.gz`.

Comment: @Jakuje "The progress bar will run fast, and then it will wait for compression, which is not observable anymore using pv." It is not what I'm observing here. The progress bar accurately visualizes the state of the whole operation. And it makes sense. Because where would gzip store that transferred data? Streams work one batch of data at a time.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is kinda possible using the lines of the file, not the bytes.
You get an accurate enough progress bar:

```
cat input_file | pv -ls $( wc -l input_file ) | gzip -c -- > compressed_file
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but can be pretty slow. In my case for a 68 GB file, the `wc` part took 45 minutes and the actual `cat`/`gzip` (then with a progressbar) 1 hour, so almost double the time.

Comment: In case of large files Intead of `wc -l` would be better to use\`stat': `pv -s $( stat -c %s)`. \`wc' will read whole file and when it's large it will take time, lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

If available, you can use 7z instead to get a percentage progress in a super simple command:

```
7z a spaCy.tar.gz spaCy.tar
```

Example output:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz (906E9),ASM,AES-NI)

Open archive: spaCy.tar.gz
--
Path = spaCy.tar.gz
Type = gzip
Headers Size = 20

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 326451200 bytes (312 MiB)

Updating archive: spaCy.tar.gz

Items to compress: 1

 32% U spaCy.tar
```